# Do Google Analytics sessions get broken when tracking UserID and ClientID across subdomains that may not send that data?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, authentication, cross-platform

I have a domain name with three subdomains.
One where a user is authenticated and two where they aren't.

I'm planning on implementing UserID tracking for Google Analytics in place of the standard ClientID tracking so as to improve our cross-device tracking.

Something I wasn't able to understand by reading the Google Analytics documentation is if sessions will be broken when moving between subdomains if all three use the same Google Analytics account and property but one passes along the UserID and the others not?